# What dimensions permit a cross product

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

A cross product is possible in a $3$D and in a $7$D system. What prevents a cross product from being possible in a vector system of higher number of dimensions? For instance $15$D or $2^n$$-1$ dimensions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615341/higher-dimensional-cross-product, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706011/why-is-cross-product-only-defined-in-3-and-7-dimensions, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185991/is-the-vector-cross-product-only-defined-for-3d

Comment: check out [Hurwitz's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras)) and [this paper by Massey](https://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F2323537)

Comment: This is **definitely** not a duplicate of the cited question. It is quite clear that the OP is talking about a binary product because he/she talks about dimensions 3 and 7, where the quaternions and octonions provide a suitable binary product. See the links in costrom's comment. I think that was a very ill-informed closure.

Comment: this question is more likely a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706011/, not the question actually cited above. The question linked here was also marked duplicate and closed, but may have more valuable information.

Comment: @costrom: thanks, I agree that the question you cite provides an answer to this one. I think it's a bad idea for questions to be closed as duplicates with an incorrect justification.